# Is it possible exclude test directories from coverage.py reports?

Tags: python, testing, software-quality, code-coverage, coverage.py

I'm kind of a rookie with python unit testing, and particularly coverage.py.  Is it desirable to have coverage reports include the coverage of your actual test files?

Here's a screenshot of my [HTML report](http://kylefox-awesome-stuff.s3.amazonaws.com/coverage.png) as an example.

You can see that the report includes `tests/test_credit_card`.  At first I was trying to omit the `tests/` directory from the reports, like so:

```
coverage html --omit=tests/ -d tests/coverage
```

I tried several variations of that command but I could *not* for the life of me get the tests/ excluded.  After accepting defeat, I began to wonder if maybe the test files are *supposed* to be included in the report.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: I had a similar problem. I didn't want extra python files (standard lib, etc.) in the coverage report. I ended up stripping them out of the XML: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293647/how-do-i-generate-coverage-xml-report-for-a-single-package/2377148#2377148

Answer (score 114):

Create `.coveragerc` file in your project root folder, and include the following:

```
[run]
omit = *tests*
```

Comment: @CynthiaSimiyu, your answer was really helpful since I needed to omit multiple directories.

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf : The omit option is **multi-string** so you can enumerate the multiple directories to omit (see example in [doc](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source.html#execution))

Comment: Alternately, add an entry to your tox.ini file `[coverage:run] omit = *tests*` which I figured out by reading http://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html

Answer (score 112):

`coverage html --omit="*/test*" -d tests/coverage`

Comment: Just to add : Multiple directories/files can be added using comma like `--omit="*/test*,config/*.conf"`

Comment: Should be top rated answer. Aint nobody wanna create coverage config files

Answer (score 56):

Leaving this here in case if any Django developer needs a .coveragerc for their project.

```
[run]
source = .
omit = ./venv/*,*tests*,*apps.py,*manage.py,*__init__.py,*migrations*,*asgi*,*wsgi*,*admin.py,*urls.py

[report]
omit = ./venv/*,*tests*,*apps.py,*manage.py,*__init__.py,*migrations*,*asgi*,*wsgi*,*admin.py,*urls.py
```

Create a file named .coveragerc on your projects root directory, paste the above code and then just run the command:

```
coverage run manage.py test
```

In addition, if you want the tests to execute faster run this command instead.

```
coverage run manage.py test --keepdb --parallel
```

This will preserve the test DB and will run the tests in parallel.

Comment: Use this answer if you are using Django, the omit lines in the `.converagerc` removes all the boilerplates from the coverage

Comment: When you say "project root", you mean where manage.py is located or even above that?

Answer (score 20):

You can specify the directories you want to exclude by creating a `.coveragerc` in the project root.

It supports wildcards (which you can use to exclude virtual environment) **and** comments (very useful for effective tracking).

The below code block shows how `omit` can be used (taken from the [latest documentation](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-4.3.3/source.html#source)) with multiple files and directories.

```
[run]
omit =
    # omit anything in a .local directory anywhere
    */.local/*
    # omit everything in /usr
    /usr/*
    # omit this single file
    utils/tirefire.py
```

In your case, you could have the following in your `.coveragerc`:

```
[run]
omit = 
    # ignore all test cases in tests/
    tests/*
```

For your question on coverage reports, you can think about testing and coverage in the following manner:

- When you run `pytest` or `unittest`, all the test cases for your source code are executed
- When you run `coverage`, it shows the part of the source code that isn't being used.
- When you run pytest with coverage (something like `pytest -v --cov`), it runs all test cases **and** shows the part of the source code that isn't being used.

**Extra**:

- You can also specify the location of your HTML report in the configuration file like:

```
[html]
directory = tests/coverage/html_report/
```

This is going to create *html*, *js*, *css*, etc. inside `tests/coverage/html_report/` everytime you run `coverage` or `pytest -v --cov`

Comment: You'll have to specify in omit `**/tests/*` to ignore nested test folders.

Answer (score 8):

You can also explicitly specify which directory has the code you want coverage on instead of saying which things to omit. In a `.coveragerc` file, if the directory of interest is called `demo`, this looks like

```
[run]
source = demo
```

Comment: In my case, specifying `--omit='*test*'` was failing to omit `tests/unit/__init__.py`, but using `--source=mypackage` worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and tried every response on this thread. Not wanting to create a .coveragerc file, I found the answer here:
https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source.html#source

you're missing the asterisk:

```
coverage html --omit=tests/* -d tests/coverage
```

this worked for me - although I don't specify a directory so I just use:

```
coverage html --omit=tests/*
```