# Pytest tests are showing up in code coverage report

Tags: python, code-coverage, pytest

When running pytest with `python -m pytest --cov=. --cov-report html:coverage`

After the coverage report is generated my tests show up in the code coverage report as being 100% covered as shown below

[image: codecov]

I've attempted to move tests into its own folder, but still yields the same results

The actual unit tests should not show up in the coverage report and are skewing my coverage amount. It should only show coverage for the actual program.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628996/is-it-possible-exclude-test-directories-from-coverage-py-reports

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44948518/1224827), creating a `.coveragerc` and adding

```
[run]
omit = 
    */test*
```

solves this issue.